# PHP: Sending an html plus plain text email I got mail with empty body

Tags: php

This is php code

```
    $boundary = uniqid("np");

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "To: $to\n";
    if (!is_null($reply_to)) $headers .= "Reply-To: $reply_to \n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\n";


    //here is the content body
    $message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
    $message .= "\n\n--" . $boundary . "\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n\n";

    //Plain text body
    $message .= "Hello,\nThis is a text email, the text/plain version.
    \n\nRegards,\nYour Name";
    $message .= "\n\n--" . $boundary . "\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n";

    $message .= "Hello, <BR> This is a text email, the <bold>html version</bold>.";
    $message .= "<BR>Regards";
    $message .= "<BR>Your Name";
    $message .= "\n\n--" . $boundary . "--";

    $sendmail = mail($to, $title, $message, $headers);
```

`$headers` variable contains:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Italia S.p.a. <root@domain.it>
To: My Name <my_name@domain.it>
Reply-To: My Alt Name <my_alt_name@domain.it> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=np536b88fc27327
```

`$message` variable contains:

```
This is a MIME encoded message.

--np536b88fc27327
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Hello,
This is a text email, the text/plain version.


Regards,
Your Name

--np536b88fc27327
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8

Hello, <BR> This is a text email, 
the <bold>html version</bold>.<BR>Regards<BR>Your Name

--np536b88fc27327--
```

Problem is: when sending using `mail($from, $to, $message, $headers)` mail is delivered, but **it's empty**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header should be..

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Check [PHP mail()](http://php.net/mail) function.

Answer (score -1):

Email headers *must* be separated by `\r\n`.

Comment: Definitively NOT true; I've other pieces of php code sending html only mail with headers separated by \n

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's un-necessary to use profanity in comments, even if you disagree.... bad form.  Although this *is* the standard, it does not mean it is the *only* way to get things to work.

Comment: @EvanL Please explain how it fails to answer the question. I have pointed out the error in the code. My brevity was due to using my phone, but the answer contained all the information needed to fix the issue. While some clients may be tolerant of `\n` headers, others may not be, and those that are may not *always* be.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The second comment was by mistake (auto-comment from review).  It has been removed.